# how to check in jquery javascript that user upload file is image or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check that user upload file is image or not.

how  i can check the type of file is image or not. are any way exist to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use useful [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) which does support the files you want to allow for upload other than other nice options.

You can  use the `accept` property of the validation plugin to allow file types you want, here is an example:

```
$("#form_id").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      accept: "gif|jpeg"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i have some other field in the form then how i can check.

Comment: @steven: You can use the `element()` method: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element. See the docs for more info.